# Trying to install updated drivers / apps on Asus computer

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop

I'm the administrator and only user of an Asus laptop and I'm trying to install an updated version of ATK package and when I run the installer I'm getting the error message shown in the pic at this link:

[image]

Any suggestions as to what might be the problem... seems like I now longer have permission to run exe's?

Comment: Does the file exist?

Comment: 1. Maker sure the file exists. 2. make sure you have admin rights. 3. if all fails you might have a corrupted file, try re downloading.

Comment: If the file exists and you do not have access to it, try right clicking the installer and running as administrator.

Comment: Hi Maher and Cestarian, have tried your suggestions to no avail. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi all, I've solved the problem. You'll see that in my opening post I said "seems like I no longer have permission to run exe's" and I was right. In case this helps anyone else with this error message, it turns out that the SYSTEM group had lost permissions to the folder location where the .msi executable was located. So I just had to right click on the folder and go into SECURITY and give SYSTEM access to the folder. Then ATK installed no problem.